# Is xdg-open by default available in every Linux distribution?

Tags: c++, linux, file-browser

I'm writing a C++ program in which I want to open the user's default browser. For Linux, I found that I can use the [xdg-open](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xdg-open) command. However, is **xdg-open** available on all Linux distributions by default?

Is there a better alternative?

Comment: The answer is obviously "NO", since no text-based distro will have it, and many minimal distros won't have it. Perhaps the question you're looking for is "Can I rely on `xdg-open` if I want to be portable between RH/CentOS, SuSE, Debian, Ubuntu?"

Answer (score 4):

xdg-open is part of the freedesktop.org suite and is, as far as I know, available to any reasonably generic desktop distribution.

That being said, you can't count on it being available on Android (though that runs a Linux kernel, and thus is a Linux), on something that just displays things on a framebuffer (older navigation systems / HMIs), something that comes without a desktop manager (some kiosk type devices) and of course extremely slimmed down things.

Answer (score 0):

If `xdg-open` does not work, on several Linux distributions (notably the Debian-like) you might try `/usr/bin/x-www-browser`.